# What's the Italian for a 'crescent' street?

Tags: word-usage, translation

*Crescent* is a common adjective used to indicate a street or terrace of houses forming an arc.[image]

What is the most appropriate way to call or describe this kind of road in Italian?

Comment: I believe that, since such a street is not typical of Italian cities, there is not a specific name for it, just like there is not an original English word for pizza, but I may well be wrong.

Comment: That may well be the case, nonetheless there must be an appropriate Italian word or phrase to refer to a crescent road.

Comment: I hope there is such a term or phrase, but my personal hunch is that there is no much better than a periphrasis explaining what we are talking about (like the one you used, or the “fila di case disposte etc.” in one of the answers).

Answer (score 6):

According to [this source](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/S/strada.php),

**Strada a mezzaluna**

I've never heard of it. It's not a common expression at all, although these streets [exist](https://goo.gl/maps/RtaUD).

Another possibility is a *locuzione* with "arco" or "semicerchio":

> La strada fa/disegna un arco
>
> [Fila di case disposte su una strada a semicerchio](http://it.bab.la/dizionario/inglese-italiano/crescent)

If it is bent like a horseshoe:

> Ferro di cavallo

In particular, a "hairpin" [on a mountain road](http://www.altarezianews.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/4382233_6_ce89_le-col-du-stelvio-a-2-758-m-d-altitude-est_b40292e98194806b948238d6312d509a.jpg):

> Tornante

Comment: I did not feel like working, so I added way too many links.

Comment: Interesting post, though *ferro di cavallo* is probably too much for a crescent :)

Comment: @Josh61 Since the topic was somewhat limited (and I am waiting for lunchtime), I took the liberty of expanding it :)

Comment: Well, a *crescent* is a street designed in that shape; the streets you mention have been so for a “massive” constraint. `;-)` There's another very similar example [at Lucca](https://www.google.it/maps/place/Lucca+LU/@43.8454672,10.5058477,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x12d5839a50ed08ef:0x792a2692654dd9e1?hl=it)

Comment: A Google search for `"strada a mezzaluna"` gives me just a few hits, including this question and a couple of quotations from Italian translations of English texts.

Answer (score 2):

There's a street near to my home, this one: [image]

and we call it "Virgolone", which means "big comma", but I don't know if it's a local name or it's used for this kind of street...